# How to add generated grid to another generated child?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to make an User List. So the program have to load all users from DataBase into the program.

My Design is finished and I have a XAML Code. Now I want to add this XAML Code into `while Reader.Read()`. So I have to add all Childrens etc. programmaticaly.

The XAML Code is:

```
<materialDesign:Card Margin="4 4 0 0"  Padding="0" Width="250">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Margin="16 16 16 4" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignHeadlineTextBlock}">User 1</TextBlock>
                    <Separator Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignLightSeparator}"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Margin="16 0 16 8" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignBody2TextBlock}">Boss</TextBlock>
                    <StackPanel Grid.Row="2" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="16 0 16 8" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                        <Button HorizontalAlignment="Right" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignToolForegroundButton}" Width="30" Padding="2 0 2 0" materialDesign:RippleAssist.IsCentered="True">
                            <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="Pencil" />
                        </Button>
                        <Button HorizontalAlignment="Right" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignToolForegroundButton}" Width="30" Padding="2 0 2 0" materialDesign:RippleAssist.IsCentered="True">
                            <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="Delete" />
                        </Button>
                        <materialDesign:PopupBox HorizontalAlignment="Right" Padding="2 0 2 0">
                            <StackPanel>
                                <Button Content="More"/>
                                <Button Content="Rights"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </materialDesign:PopupBox>

                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </materialDesign:Card>
```

I'm using MaterialDesign in XAML.
So I have to add all these Childrens to Code-Behind (Im working without MVVM cuz the whole program is code-behind so i dont want to recode the whole program).

My Code until now is:

```
while(reader.Read())
                {
                    #region MaterialDesignCard
                    MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf.Card card = new MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf.Card();
                    card.Margin = new Thickness(4, 4, 0, 0);
                    card.Padding = new Thickness(0);
                    card.Width = 250;
                    #endregion
                    #region Grid
                    Grid grid = new Grid();

                    #endregion


                    wrapPanelEmployees.Children.Add(card);
                }
```

No I have to add the Grid into the card. But I can't code it this way:

```
card.Children.Add(grid)
```

How else I can add a generated grid to another generated children (card) ?

Comment: Is Card  a UserControl or what is it?

Comment: A "ContentControl" https://github.com/ButchersBoy/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/blob/master/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf/Card.cs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you could cast the `Content` property of the `Card` to a `Grid` and then add the element to its `Children` collection:

```
Grid grid = card.Content as Grid;
if(grid != null)
    grid.Children.Add(grid);
```

**Edit:** If you are actually creating the Grid element programmatically you should set the Content property of the Card control to the Grid:

```
card.Content = grid;
```

Comment: mh I get no Error, but I don't see the result if I click a Button for example to run this code nothing happens.

Comment: You really need to read this through: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: What does the Content property of the card return when you debug?

Comment: I guess nothing (don't know much about debugging functions). But If i add a card.Content = "Test"; Then I see a result. I see the generated card with "test" in it. So the way to add the grid to Content is right I guess.

Comment: Set the Content property to the Grid then: card.Content = grid;

Comment: I have tested 2 Ways now.
`Grid grid = card.Content as Grid;
            if (grid != null)
            {
                grid.Background = Brushes.AliceBlue;
                card.Content = grid;
            }`
Debugging: card.Content = null

`Grid grid2 = new Grid();
            grid2.Background = Brushes.Black;
            card.Content = grid2;`
Debugging: card.Content = System.Windows.Controls.Grid
BUT there is still no result. (invisible).

Comment: Of course you also need to add some elements to the grid...grid.Children.Add(new TextBlock() { Text = "test" });